# issue with ansible register: copy: and stdout

Tags: ansible, stdout, nexus

I have an Ansible 2.6 playbook that is trying to run a couple (want to add more when I get the issue fixed) commands on a series of Cisco Nexus switches and write the output to a file (one file per switch).  The playbook runs successfully but I cannot seem to get the output into a readable format.  Thanks in advance for anythinng to try!

Example output:

Module 1: v1.0\n             Module 1: v1.0\n             Module 2: v1.0\n             Module 7: v2.0\n             Module 8: v2.0\n  Fabric Power Sequencer Firmware: Module 0: version v3.0\n  Microcontroller Firmware:        version v1.2.2.0\n  QSFP Microcontroller Firmware:   \n             Module 1: v1.7.0.0\n             Module 2: v1.7.0.0\n  SFP Microcontroller Firmware:   \n

### PLAYBOOK:

```
    - hosts: NX-API
      gather_facts: false
      connection: network_cli
      order: sorted


      tasks:
        - name: run show version on remote devices
          nxos_command:
            commands:
              - show version
              - show interface status
          register: pre_check

        - name: save output to /home/ansible/PRECHECK/
          copy:
            content:
                with_items:
                   - "{{ pre_check.stdout[0] }}"
                   - "{{ pre_check.stdout[1] }}"
            dest: "/home/PRECHECK/pre_check_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the playbook works but I find several issues:

- the `with_item` in the copy task is ill placed here. As it is written in your playbook, what you should get is a file filled with json data (*e.g.* `{"with_items": ["whatever {{ pre_check.stdout[0] }} expands to", "whatever {{ pre_check.stdout[1] }} expands to"]}`;
- if you were de-indenting the `with_items` you would execute the task twice for each switch. That would then do n-1 iterations for nothing as the last one would override the content of the destination files which does not change;

Ain't there a `pre_check.stdout_lines` variable defined by the nxos_command module ? (Doc says yes) which is the same as stdout but as a list of lines, not the whole bulk of the console output. Would something like:

```
    - name: save output to /home/ansible/PRECHECK/
      copy:
        content: "{{ (pre_check.stdout_lines[0] + pre_check.stdout_lines[1]) | join('\n') }}"
        dest: "/home/PRECHECK/pre_check_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

work. Assumes `stdout_lines` is a list of list. But I believe:

```
    - name: save output to /home/ansible/PRECHECK/
      copy:
        content: "{{ (pre_check.stdout[0] + pre_check.stdout[1] }}"
        dest: "/home/PRECHECK/pre_check_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

Should work as well, assuming there is a final `\n` at the end of `pre_check.stdout[0]` otherwise you'll need to add it yourself.

Comment: yea 'stdout_lines' is a valid option in place of 'stdout' , but either way it does not format correctly (or least the way I want it to).  So it looks like it is taking each command and then making the output of each command a list element, such that the 'sh version' command output is the "[0]" and the 'sh int status' command output is the "[1]".

Comment: @RobertCampbell drastically changed my answer. Hopefully this will be more helpful.

Comment: thanks!  yes, my 'with_items' was ill-conceived, to be sure. The content: "{{ (pre_check.stdout[0] + pre_check.stdout[1] }}"  line is a winner.  Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect formating now:Reason: Reset Requested by CLI command reload
  System version: 7.3(2)N1(1)
  Service:

plugin
  Core Plugin, Ethernet Plugin, Fc Plugin

Active Package(s)--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Port          Name               Status    Vlan      Duplex  Speed   Type
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Eth1/1        S60G3SP001-e1/1    connected f-path    full    40G     WSP-Q40GLR4
Eth1/2        UPLINK FEX111      connected 1         full    40G     WSP-Q40GLR4